# how to use activerecord count_all_result()? with specific column?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I want to get count of specific column of table using codeigniter active record, something like this:

```
$this->db->count_all_results('t.column1');
```

so how can i change this db_active_record function? for any help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To count a specific column, You would do this;

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('column' => $column);
return $query->num_rows(); // This is what you're after...
```

Comment: I have many joined table and a lot of other where condition just i want to take count of t1.column1 instead of data selection.

Comment: You can use count_all_results() instead of get().

Comment: But `count_all_result();` make query like `SELECT COUNT(*)`, but i need `SELECT COUNT(t.column1)`

Answer (score 0):

create the query in your model, load it in your controller and then just count the array items in the view.

for example:
Model:

```
function getAll() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->order_by('user_ad', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

controller:

```
$this->load->model('Users');
$data['allusers'] = $this->Users->getAll();

this->load->view('users', $data);
```

and in your  view you can use

```
count($allusers);
```